# How do I fill in a javascript widget before it autofills its default text with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fill in the date of a javascript widget to then download data for a specified date.  Using clear() or Ctrl+a Delete will both empty the text field, however, when sending the string containing the date, the widget autofills with a default date and ignores the keys sent to it.
Can anybody help me with a way to properly fill in the date of the widget?

```
import requests
import re
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys as KEYS

url ='https://rtba.spectraenergy.com/InformationalPosting/Default.aspx?bu=TE&Type=OA'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/Program Setup Files/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ctl01_oaDefault_ucDate_rdpDate_dateInput_text"]')
# ActionChains(driver).click(date).send_keys("1/1/2020").perform()
ActionChains(driver).click(date).key_down(KEYS.CONTROL).send_keys("a").send_keys(KEYS.DELETE).send_keys("1/1/2020").perform()

# Find the button, call it downloadEXCEL
downloadEXCEL = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Downloadable Format')
ActionChains(driver).click(downloadEXCEL).perform()                         # Click the button
```

I know the send_keys is working because the commented out line here

```
# ActionChains(driver).click(date).send_keys("1/1/2020").perform()
```

will send the date and the field will contain the two dates concatenated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only needed to "take my finger off control" so to speak

```
ActionChains(driver).click(date).key_down(KEYS.CONTROL).send_keys("a").key_up(KEYS.CONTROL).send_keys("1/1/2020").send_keys(KEYS.RETURN).perform()
```

Using key_up(KEYS.CONTROL) after I was finished with 'CTRL + a' did the trick.